# Batch Apex on Account not working

Tags: apex, batch

Working on a requirement where on Account if NSC(checkbox field) and Status is Active And Case Record Type is equal to NSC Action then every year a Task on Case **should be created** whose due date is Case : Anniversary(formula field) + 330 days.Below is the workflow criteria that was written but workflow won't work as there is a recursive process for Task (every year).

Tried writing below code,how Do I go about this in Query and process the execute method.Thanks in advance

```
    **Account: NSC EQUALS True) AND (Account: Status EQUALS Active) AND (Case: Case Record Type EQUALS NSC Action )**

  **Bath Apex**

   public class Account_CloneCasesOnAnniversary implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
 {
   String errors = '';
   integer todayday = date.today().day();
   Integer currentmonth = date.today().month();
   List<Task> taskCreateList = new List<Task>();


public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
   return Database.getQueryLocator('select NSC,Status,() from Account ');

   }

public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {
    if(scope.isEmpty()) return;

    for(Account account : scope) {
        if(account.cases.size() > 0) {

            }
        }
    }

    for(Database.SaveResult result : srList ) {
        if(!result.isSuccess()) {
            String errMsg = result.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
         } 
        index++;
        }

        List<Task> lstTask = [select WhatId, Anniversary__c, priority from Task];
       system.debug('All Tasks' + lstTask);

    for (Task taskObj : lstTask ) {

        Task addTask = new Task();
        taskCreateList.add();
    }
    system.debug('Tasks' + taskCreateList);

    // check for task list is empty or not
    if(!taskCreateList.isEmpty()) {
        // insert task list Of Task which were cloned  
        Database.SaveResult[] srListTask = Database.insert(taskCreateList, false);
        Integer indexTask = 0;

        for(Database.SaveResult resultTask : srListTask ) {
            if(!resultTask.isSuccess()) {
                String errMsgTask = resultTask.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
            } 
            indexTask++;
        } 
    }*/

    }       

public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
 }
```

Comment: If I understand your question, you're saying that the task would normally be created as time-based 330 days in advance? What I suspect you're really looking for is the task to run when the case is actually `today()-330 days`. Is that correct? That's the only thing that makes sense to me. That would seem to be what your query needs to be based on each day once your records are returned from the iterator.

Comment: Yes. So, Its is like , Due date on Task will be Case : Anniversary + 330 days (after 330 days from Anniversary date) .

Comment: Yes and it would be yearly (time based)

Comment: Hope I'm clear to the specified requirement.

Comment: You say a "Task should run". Creating the Task is one thing, "running a task" is another. If someone is manually "performing" the Task and that's the date it's due, I'd talk with your business people to find out when they `really` need it created and have your batch process it at 30 days before, 60 before, etc. If there's automation you want to do, that's a different story. It's not clear to me where you're stuck. You're going to need to either query or sort within each batchable context for the records that meet your criteria. You don't have any code to do that yet.

Comment: Edited the post, it should be that the task should be created. I need help in writing the query (as I tried) and not able to proceed further.Also, then, how do I proceed with processing records in the execute method though, have tried writing the code.It would be great if you can support me write it